# Comparar valores com diferentes condicionais na mesma tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ao efetuar um `SELECT COUNT(*)`  na view `vwNotaFiscal` obtenho o total de linhas: `3498`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.vwNotaFiscal
WHERE 
tbEmbarques_emissao BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,'01/05/2016',103) AND CONVERT(DATE,'31/05/2016',103)
AND (dataRecebimento is not null and recebimento_embarque is not null)
```

Ao selecionar as notas fiscais que foram entregues no prazo, eu efetuo o  `SELECT` abaixo e me retorna `2697`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.vwNotaFiscal
WHERE 
tbEmbarques_emissao BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,'01/05/2016',103) AND CONVERT(DATE,'31/05/2016',103)
AND (dataRecebimento is not null and recebimento_embarque is not null) 
AND (datarecebimento <= dataprevista OR datarecebimento <= dataAgendamento)
```

Ou seja, do total `3498` eu tenho `2697` dentro do prazo, assim os `801` restantes dessa conta seriam os atrasados. Porém ao efetuar a consulta para verificar isso, o valor vem incorreto: `1293`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.vwNotaFiscal
WHERE 
tbEmbarques_emissao BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,'01/05/2016',103) AND CONVERT(DATE,'31/05/2016',103)
AND (dataRecebimento is not null and recebimento_embarque is not null) 
AND (datarecebimento > dataprevista OR datarecebimento > dataAgendamento)
```

Estou buscando uma forma de verificar esses registros e compará-los para saber o que está retornando a mais nesse último `SELECT`. Encontrei os comandos `INTERSECT` e `EXCEPT` porém não me ajudaram na solução.

Comment: Marcelo, pelo o que consegui extrair da sua conversa com o @CiganoMorrisonMendez, apenas uma das datas deve ser utilizada na comparação, pelo nome dos seus campos, posso inferir que a `dataPrevista` estará sempre preenchida e será utilizada caso a `dataAgendamento`esteja nula, ou pelo a `dataAgendamento` tem precedência sobre a `dataPrevista`.

Comment: Exatamente, @TobyMosque.

Comment: Curiosidade, e se você fizesse isso: AND NOT (datarecebimento <= dataprevista OR datarecebimento <= dataAgendamento)

Comment: Nada, @cantoni... Adicionando a linha, a contagem retorna `103`, o valor não é esse.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade, sem acesso aos dados fica difícil ajudar em casos como esse. Mas eu te sugiro fazer algumas verificações, exemplo, os 801 registros não foram achados via SQL, mas fazendo (3498-2697=801). Pode ser que existam registros no seu banco que não atendam o SQL dos fora do prazo que você está tentando fazer. Talvez só os 103 encontrados pela minha logica e do Cigano atendam. O restante deve ter algum problema nos dados que não fazem eles serem retornados. É hora de analisar alguns registros e verificar o que acontece com os dados. Exporte tudo para o Excel e faça filtro lá.

Comment: @cantoni justamente o que estou tentando fazer agora. Quero uma forma válida de comparar os valores retornados entre essas duas consultas.

Answer (score 2):

```
(datarecebimento <= dataprevista OR datarecebimento <= dataAgendamento)
```

Não é a negação lógica de

```
(datarecebimento > dataprevista OR datarecebimento > dataAgendamento)
```

Pela sua lógica de notas no prazo:

- Data de Recebimento precisa ser anterior ou igual à Data Prevista; ou
- Data de Recebimento precisa ser anterior ou igual à Data do Agendamento.

A lógica do complementar disso, então, deve ser:

- Data de Recebimento precisa ser **posterior** ou igual à Data Prevista; **e**
- Data de Recebimento precisa ser **posterior** ou igual à Data do Agendamento.

[Isto é lógica proposicional de De Morgan](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoremas_de_De_Morgan#L.C3.B3gica_proposicional). Se a data de recebimento é anterior a uma das duas outras datas (prevista ou de agendamento), a encomenda chegou no prazo, e por isso não cabe o operador `OR`.

Portanto, a sentença certa é:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.vwNotaFiscal
WHERE 
tbEmbarques_emissao BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,'01/05/2016',103) AND CONVERT(DATE,'31/05/2016',103)
AND (dataRecebimento is not null and recebimento_embarque is not null) 
AND (datarecebimento > dataprevista AND datarecebimento > dataAgendamento)
```

Comment: O problema que ao utilizar o operandor `AND`, eu afirmo que as duas datas do registro precisam obedecer essa condição, correto? Sendo que os registros obedecem apenas uma dessas duas datas como critério de cada vez. No caso do seu `SELECT` eu tive um total de `103` registros apenas.

Comment: Então possivelmente você terá que aumentar o critério. Não sei como está seu banco, mas mais algumas coisas terão de ser conferidas.

Comment: Esse será um problema, pois não há mais critérios a serem atendidos.

Comment: Outra alternativa seria materializar o resultado de cada condição em separado, mas [eu precisaria de um Fiddle pra isso](http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Comment: Verei se há como disponibilizar

Answer (score 1):

Marcelo, já que `dataAgendamento` tem precedência sobre `dataprevista` e apenas uma das duas datas deve ser usada na comparação, então utilize o `ISNULL`.

```
DECLARE @DataIni as DATE;
DECLARE @DataFin as DATE;

SET @DataIni = '2016-05-01';
SET @DataFin = '2016-05-31';

WITH CTE_Pedidos as (
    SELECT 
        notaFiscalId, 
        CAST(CASE 
            WHEN datarecebimento <= IsNull(dataAgendamento, dataprevista) THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS BIT) IsNoPrazo
    FROM dbo.vwNotaFiscal
    WHERE 
        tbEmbarques_emissao BETWEEN @DataIni AND @DataFin AND 
        (dataRecebimento is not null and recebimento_embarque is not null) 
)

SELECT
    Total.Quantidade AS Total,
    NoPrazo.Quantidade AS NoPrazo,
    ForaPrazo.Quantidade AS ForaPrazo
FROM
    (SELECT COUNT(notaFiscalId) AS Quantidade FROM CTE_Pedidos) AS Total,
    (SELECT COUNT(notaFiscalId) AS Quantidade FROM CTE_Pedidos WHERE IsNoPrazo = 1) AS NoPrazo,
    (SELECT COUNT(notaFiscalId) AS Quantidade FROM CTE_Pedidos WHERE IsNoPrazo = 0) AS ForaPrazo,
```